# Suitebar is moving on quick launch link click

Tags: hyperlink, suitebar, anchor-tags, menu

I have a long page with many headings in the content area. The quick launch is set up with those headings as adress in the anchor tags.

```
<a class="static menu-item ms-core-listMenu-item ms-displayInline ms-navedit-linkNode" tabindex="0" href="#peoplelookbook"><span class="additional-background ms-navedit-flyoutArrow"><span class="menu-item-text">people lookbook+</span></span></a>
```

When I click the menu item, the site jumps to the right heading in the content. But the suitebar slips a little bit out of the window.
Someone can help me to get this right?

[image: suitebar screenshot]

I just recognized that this is only happening in Chrome and not IE.
When I click an anchor link to a heading on the page, the body slips 17px out of the top page.

Comment: It sounds like one of your styles that changes on the click event has a different position or float. Try hitting F12 and using the CSS tab before & after the click to determine what's changed.

Comment: But I have not changed anything there. Could you please explain me what CSS tab you mean? And in what browser?

Comment: When you have the site open in your browser (IE, Chrome, Firefox), you can hit F12 on the keyboard to access a debugger console. This console should have several tabs like HTML, CSS, Scripts, etc. The CSS one will show you what styles & formatting are being applied to the page when it renders.

Comment: I can only choose between :active :visited :hover and :focus. And this is only for the styling of the specific element. Can you please say me exactly where I have to look for what?